# How to find outliers in multivariate data with weak covariance

Tags: python, pca, outliers, multivariate-testing, mahalanobis

I have used PCA and Mahalanobis distance to find outliers. But in both cases, only the highest or lowest values are detected as outliers. I am looking for a way that any data point that does not follow a certain correlation between output and 3 inputs can be identified as an outlier.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "any data point that does not follow a certain correlation between output and 3 inputs can be identified as an outlier."? Also, the question may be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I have multivariate data (3 independent, 1 dependent variable). I am trying to define the outliers based on not only their values being very high or low, but rather the points not 'behaving' similar to other data points. I hope this makes it clearer. I will surely post this on stats.stackexchange! Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.